# Keyboard doesn't show up when SAMSUNG Multi-Window Sdk is implemented on galaxy S3 running Android 4.2 and 4.3

Tags: android, keyboard, searchbar, samsung-mobile-sdk, multi-window

When I add samsung multiwindow sdk, I realised that on galaxy phones running android 4.2 and 4.3 have a problem on showing soft-keyboard. 
If I don't use the samsung multiwindow sdk, soft-keyboard works fine.
I'm using [this searchbar library](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView). Maybe it's related with this library too. Also I've tried to force to show soft-keyboard with the following code; but still keyboard is not visible.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,  InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Manifest file ([site](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/multiwindow)):

```
   <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
   <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable" android:value="true" />
```

Problem (Soft keyboard isn't shown on focus of searcbar) that I've faced with is because of the enabling multiwindow meta-data. So I defined two 'bool.xml's under values-v18 and values-v19 in order to disable samsung multiwindow library below Kitkat.

changed in to this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable" android:value="@bool/samsung_multi_window" />
```